# How to use nginx to proxy remote server?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have a route in a web server which needs to fetch a file from remote server and then process the content.

I want nginx to proxy this fetch action so that I can take the advantages of cache and performance.

At first I think I can use `x-accel-redirect`, but as I need to process the content, I think I cannot.

Second I think I can just create a proxy_pass route for this purpose, but I also need to restrict this route to be accessed only from my web server.

What is the best practice? Adding `allow 127.0.0.1` in this route?

Answer (score 0):

The internal directive will restrict the route in this manner, allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; will have the same effect.

If you are intending to process the content within Nginx eg with the subs filter module then dont forget to disable gzip for this location

Comment: Are you sure `internal` will work as expected? After reading official doc I think it will also block requests from local host.